# How to change the default folder of downloading (for browser)?

Tags: android, browser, download

I am using this code to download songs from a Uri.

```
String url = "url of song that will download";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
Download.this.startActivity(intent);
Download.this.finish();
Toast.makeText(Download.this,
  "The file you are downloading will be saved in your SD Card downloads folder.",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

By default my songs saved in SDCards/Downloads folder.i want to save my songs in SDCards/Device folder.

Kindly suggest me, how can i change the downloading path of browser programmatically.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot change browser settings by code. Sorry.